# $routeProvider not redirecting

Tags: angularjs

I have config() like this.

```
function config($httpProvider, $routeProvider) {

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptorService');

$routeProvider
  .when('/detail/:id', {
    controller: 'CourseDetailController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    templateUrl: 'templates/course-detail.html'
  })
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
}
```

View

```
<a class="course--module course--link" href="/#/detail/{{ course._id   }}">
```

when course is clicked `URL` is encoded like below and no routing seems to be happening.

```
http://localhost:5000/#!/#%2Fdetail%2F57029ed4795118be119cc43d
```

I tried

1. Removed `/#` from  `href = "/#/detail/{{ course._id }}"`, but this time `URL` becomes `http://localhost:5000/detail/57029ed4795118be119cc43d` and not picked up angular router and making a server request instead.
2. Manually visited `URL` in the address bar
   `http://localhost:5000/#!/detail/F57029ed4795118be119cc43d` 
   without encoded character and this time view is changed correctly.

Any idea?.

Answer (score 1):

Do this in your config,

```
function config($httpProvider, $routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

And try using ng-href

```
<a class="course--module course--link" ng-href="/#/detail/{{ course._id   }}">
```

OR

Just add a `!` after your `#` in href

```
<a class="course--module course--link" ng-href="/#!/detail/{{ course._id   }}">
```

Comment: doesn't  seem to be working

Comment: Are you using angular 1.6 ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the browser level API, with the object window, or you can inject the $window reference in your controller.

- `window.location.href="http://www.google.com";`
- `$window.location.href="http://www.google.com";`

Comment: If I solved your problem please accept the answer.